# Why is my Simple jQuery Function not Defined?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm very new to jQuery, and I would like some insight on how to make this very simple jQuery function something that can actually execute. I am trying to apply jQuery to WordPress, hence is why my code begins with "jQuery" rather than the standard "$". The task I wish to accomplish with this little test function is simply append the word "test" to the end of a block of test, but as it stands my function is returning a " Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined" error. The code I'm trying to execute is fully shown below:

```
jQuery(function () {
    function test() {
        $( ".about-us" ).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
    }
})
```

And this is how I'm calling said script on my page (at the very bottom):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mysite/wp-
content/themes/RainForest/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
test();
//--></script>
```

Any insights that could help enlighten me on how to solve this and future conundrums would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to add jquery library first

Comment: Your function is not in scope of the second `<script>` block. You need to move the function definition *outside* of jQuery's document.ready handler

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because your function is not in scope of the second `<script>` block. You need to move the function definition *outside* of jQuery's document.ready handler.

However note that the pattern in your original code is pretty redundant as you're include a document.ready event handler anyway. You may as well use that instead of calling `test()` manually.

Also note that you need to include jQuery.js in your page - although I assume this is just a mistake in your question only. Try this:

```
jQuery(function() {
  $(".about-us").append("<p>Test</p>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mysite/wpcontent/themes/RainForest/slider.js"></script>
```